# Prove that $\triangle ABC=\left(\triangle DEF \cdot \triangle XYZ\right)^{1/2}$

Tags: geometry, area

In $\triangle ABC$ , $D$, $E$, $F$ are points on the sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$. Also, $A$, $B$, $C$ are points on $YZ$, $ZX$, $XY$ of $\triangle XYZ$ for which $EF \parallel YZ$, $FD \parallel ZX$, $DE \parallel XY$. Prove that area of $$\triangle ABC=\left(\triangle DEF \cdot \triangle XYZ\right)^{1/2}$$

I really have no idea how to approach this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The only thing that I know is $\triangle DEF \sim \triangle XYZ$.

I do not know about homothety and am expected to only solve this problem using elementary techniques such as similarity, Menelaus theorem, Ceva Theorem etc. Trigonometry is also allowed.

Comment: Consider $P=XD\cap YE\cap ZF$ (why this point exists?) and try to prove that $S_{ADPF}=\sqrt{S_{DPF}S_{YPZ}}$.

Comment: Even when you "have no idea" about a problem, you can provide context. Eg, if this is a textbook exercise, say something about the results/techniques discussed in the chapter; if it's an online challenge/contest, say something about the level of difficulty. Also: What tools should be used here? Elementary geometry? Fancier transformation stuff? Trigonometry? Coordinates and/or vectors? The more you can tell us, the better the  chances that someone can provide an answer helpful to you without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you know or using techniques beyond your skill level.

Comment: This is an exercise from a book called "Challenge and Thrills of Pre-College Mathematics" and I am expected to solve it using only elementary techniques such as similarity, Menelaus theorem, Ceva's theorem, etc. I am comfortable with using trigonometry too.

Comment: @richrow Can you please say why they will be concurrent? I tried to use the trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem but I am stuck. I need to prove that $$\dfrac{AE \cdot CD \cdot BF \cdot YC \cdot XB \cdot ZA}{EC \cdot DB \cdot FA \cdot AY \cdot CX \cdot BZ}=1$$ in order to prove that they are concurrent.

Comment: @PopularPower Are you familiar with homothety?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @PopularPower: That's good to know, thanks. You should [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3801683/edit) to show the information there, since comments are easily overlooked or might be obscured.

Comment: Can I argue that since $\triangle DEF \sim \triangle XYZ$ and that I can scale $\triangle DEF$ without rotating it to make $\triangle XYZ$, that there must be a point from which we scale them? And that point is $P=XD\cap YE\cap ZF$. I do not know it's rigorous or not. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @PopularPower Try to show the more general (and pretty useful) fact: If you have two triangles $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta XYZ$, then $AX, BY, CZ$ are concurrent iff the points $AB \cap XY, BC \cap YZ, CA \cap ZX$ are collinear. The original concurrency follows from this, since you can take the latter line to be the "line at infinity"

Comment: And as a sidenote, for Euclidean Geometry, especially for olympiads, a much, much better book than C&ToPCM is "Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads" by Evan Chen. The former don't even touches on projective geometry or barycentric coordinates, though it's a good idea to get comfortable with the fundamental synthetic stuff in C&ToPCM

Comment: @Lelouch I could not understand what you mean by "line of infinity".

Comment: And thank you very much for the suggestion of that book. It's explanations are superb.

Comment: @PopularPower It's probably best understood in the context of projective geometry, till you learn that properly you can probably hand wave the notion a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose that $[XYZ]$ (the area of $\triangle XYZ$) is $1$, and the ratio of similarity between $\triangle DEF$ and $\triangle XYZ$ is $r<1$ (so that $[DEF] = r^2$).

Let $a, b, c$ be the distances between $EF$ and $YZ$, between $ZX$ and $FD$, and between $XY$ and $DE$, respectively.

Then we have $[AEF] = \frac a2 \cdot EF$, $[BFD] = \frac b2 \cdot FD$, and $[CDE] = \frac c2 \cdot DE$ by the formula for triangle area; adding them together, we have $$[ABC] - [DEF] = \frac a2 \cdot EF + \frac b2 \cdot FD + \frac c2 \cdot DE.$$

On the other hand, we have $[AEY] = \frac a2 \cdot AY$, $[AFZ] = \frac a2 \cdot AZ$, $[BFZ] = \frac b2 \cdot BZ$, $[BDX] = \frac b2 \cdot BX$, $[CDX] = \frac c2 \cdot CX$, and $[CEY] = \frac c2 \cdot CY$; adding them together and noting that for example $YZ = AY + AZ$, we have $$[XYZ] - [ABC] = \frac a2 \cdot YZ + \frac b2 \cdot ZX + \frac c2 \cdot XY.$$

Because $r$ is the ratio of similarity between $\triangle DEF$ and $\triangle XYZ$, we have $EF = r \cdot YZ$, $FD = r \cdot ZX$, and $DE = r \cdot XY$, which tells us that
$$
    [ABC] - [DEF] = r([XYZ] - [ABC]).
$$
Recall that we assumed $[XYZ] = 1$ and $[DEF] = r^2$, so we now have $[ABC] - r^2 = r(1 - [ABC])$. Solving, we get $[ABC] = r$, so $[ABC] = \sqrt{r^2 \cdot 1} = \sqrt{[DEF] \cdot [XYZ]}$.

Comment: a really fantastic solution! Simple and intuitive. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Say, $\triangle DEF = p$, then triangle $\triangle XYZ = p(t^2)$ where t is the ratio of sides of $\triangle XYZ$ to $\triangle ABC$.

$\triangle XYZ = [XDEY] + [YEFZ] + [XDFZ] + \triangle DEF$ (3 parallelograms + $\triangle DEF$).

Say, $EF = a, FD = b, DE = c$

$\triangle XYZ = \dfrac{1}{2}[c(1+t)h_3 + a(1+t)h_1 + b(1+t)h_2] + \triangle DEF$
$p(t^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}[c(1+t)h_3 + a(1+t)h_1 + b(1+t)h_2] + p$

$2p(t^2) = c(1+t)h_3 + a(1+t)h_1 + b(1+t)h_2 + 2p$ ...(i)

Now, $\triangle ABC = \triangle CDE + \triangle AEF + \triangle BDF + \triangle DEF$

$\triangle ABC = \dfrac{1}{2}(c.h_3 + a.h_2 + b.h_1) + p$ ...(ii)

From (i) and (ii),

$p(t^2) = (\triangle ABC - p)(1+t) + p$

$p(t-1) = \triangle ABC - p$

$\triangle ABC = pt = \sqrt{p.pt^2} = \sqrt{\triangle DEF.\triangle XYZ}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. This is very simple.